# How to stop custom powershell completion from falling back to suggesting files?

Tags: powershell, completion

I am writing a custom PowerShell completion hook for a native command using:

```
$scriptblock = {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
    ...
};
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName my-command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Using:

```
my-completion-generator $commandLineInfo | ForEach-Object { 
  ...
  [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($value, $display, 'ParameterValue', $tooltip)
}
```

To register suggestions that are being created by another command (`my-completion-generator`) that is in charge of the completions.

But there are situations where there are no reasonable suggestions to make so the script never calls `[System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($value, $display, 'ParameterValue', $tooltip)` and in that case PowerShell seems to fall back to suggesting files in the current directory. I can see that it isn't a completely crazy fallback to have in general but it is very unhelpful in some situations. I'd rather just have no suggestions at all.

How do I go about making that happen? If I check for no suggestions and add an empty suggestion then it still does the same (falls back to suggesting files) and there is no non-empty suggestion that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this might be impossible at the moment. I created an issue [#18233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18233) and it has been marked as a duplicate of [#7215](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7215).